# Какое из представленных решений задачи наиболее оптимальное и почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, анализ

Задача:

> Лиза и Джефф делают новую систему для хранения данных участников чемпионата мира по квиддичу.
>   Вас попросили реализовать для этой системы следующий модуль: задано несколько дат в формате
>   dd/mm/yyyy. Выведите самую позднюю из этих дат в формате yyyy/mm/dd.

Входные данные:

> В первой строке входа содержится одно целое число N — количество дат (1 ≤ N ≤ 100). Каждая
>   из последующих N строк содержит даты в формате dd/mm/yyyy. Все даты корректны, номер года
>   — целое положительное число, меньшее 104.

Выходные данные:

> Выведите самую позднюю дату в формате “yyyy/mm/dd” по одной на строку.

Первый вариант:

```
n, data, data2 = int(input()), [], []
for i in range(n):
    data.append(input())
for i in data:
    data2.append(((int(int(i[6:])*12+int(i[3:5])*31+int(i[:2]))),data.index(i)))
print(f'{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][6:]}/{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][3:5]}/{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][:2]}')
```

Второй вариант:

```
 n = int(input()) 
Mymax = '0000/00/00' 
for i in range(n): 
    date = input() 
    date = date[-4:] + date[2:6] + date[:2] 
    if int(Mymax[:4]) < int(date[:4]): 
        Mymax = date 
    elif int(Mymax[:4]) == int(date[:4]): 
        if int(Mymax[5:7]) < int(date[5:7]): 
            Mymax = date 
        elif int(Mymax[5:7]) == int(date[5:7]): 
            if int(Mymax[8:10]) < int(date[8:10]): 
                Mymax = date 
print(Mymax)
```

Comment: Сначала расскажите, что понимать под "оптимальным".

Comment: Первый алгоритм неправильно находит максимальную дату для `data = ['01/01/2000', '01/02/2001', '06/01/2010', '06/07/2018']` -- пишет что `2010/01/06`, а не `2018/07/06`, второй алгоритм правильно нашел

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю от себя варианты

## Вариант 1.

```
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y')

n = int(input())
max_date = max(to_date(input()) for i in range(n))

max_date = max_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print(max_date)
```

Тест:

```
items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
max_date = max(to_date(date) for date in items)
print(max_date)  # 2039-04-11 00:00:00    

max_date = max_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print(max_date)  # 2039/04/11
```

## Вариант 2:

Без `datetime`:

```
def to_items(date):
    # return list(map(int, value.split('/')[::-1]))
    # Оптимизация кода выше:
    # "10/11/2018" -> (2018, 11, 10)
    return int(date[6:]), int(date[3:5]), int(date[:2])

n = int(input())
items = [input() for i in range(n)]

max_date = max(items, key=to_items)
print(max_date)  # 11/04/2039

d, m, y = max_date.split('/')
print('{}/{}/{}'.format(y, m, d))

# Или:
max_date = '/'.join(max_date.split('/')[::-1])
print(max_date)
```

Тест:

```
items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
max_date = max(items, key=to_items)
print(max_date)  # 11/04/2039

d, m, y = max_date.split('/')
print('{}/{}/{}'.format(y, m, d))  # 2039/04/11

# Или:
max_date = '/'.join(max_date.split('/')[::-1])
print(max_date)  # 2039/04/11
```

---

## Давайте проверим что быстрее:

Для этого воспользуюсь модулем `timeit`, в нем опишу алгоритмы и задам количество повторов в `100000`:

```
from timeit import timeit

NUMBER = 100000

result = timeit(
    stmt="""\
data = items
data2 = []
for i in items:
    data2.append(((int(int(i[6:])*12+int(i[3:5])*31+int(i[:2]))),data.index(i)))

max_date = f'{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][6:]}/{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][3:5]}/{data[int(data2[len(data2)-1][1])-1][:2]}'
""",
    setup='''\
items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
''', number=NUMBER
)
print(result)

result = timeit(
    stmt="""\
Mymax = '0000/00/00'
for date in items:
    date = date[-4:] + date[2:6] + date[:2]
    if int(Mymax[:4]) < int(date[:4]):
        Mymax = date
    elif int(Mymax[:4]) == int(date[:4]):
        if int(Mymax[5:7]) < int(date[5:7]):
            Mymax = date
        elif int(Mymax[5:7]) == int(date[5:7]):
            if int(Mymax[8:10]) < int(date[8:10]):
                Mymax = date
""",
    setup='''\
items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
''', number=NUMBER
)
print(result)

result = timeit(
    stmt="""\
max_date = max(to_date(date) for date in items)
max_date = max_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
""",
    setup='''\
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y')

items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
''', number=NUMBER
)
print(result)

result = timeit(
    stmt="""\
max_date = max(items, key=to_items)
max_date = '/'.join(max_date.split('/')[::-1])
""",
    setup='''\
def to_items(date):
    return int(date[6:]), int(date[3:5]), int(date[:2])

items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
''', number=NUMBER
)
print(result)

result = timeit(
    stmt="""\
max_date = max(items, key=to_items)
d, m, y = max_date.split('/')
max_date = '{}/{}/{}'.format(y, m, d)
""",
    setup='''\
def to_items(date):
    return int(date[6:]), int(date[3:5]), int(date[:2])

items = ["10/11/2018", "22/11/2017", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007", "11/04/2039", "14/10/2007"]
''', number=NUMBER
)
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
1.0591819698786455
1.2393701934803378
7.356030745787709
0.7687656517399457
0.7521441763075742
```

Первые 2 - ваши алгоритмы, 3 - алгоритм с `datetime` и оставшиеся это через разделение строки даты на коллекцию.

Как видно, код с `datetime` самый медленный, зато самый понятный и короткий. А 4 и 5 самые быстрые, но немного сложнее выглядят.